# Tornado async endpoint does not works

Tags: asynchronous, tornado

I have two microservices:

- **a service**

Tornado service with two endpoints: `/foo` and `/bar`

`/foo`

```
async def get(...):
   x = await test()
   return x

async def test():
    y = call to b service, FooBar rpc
    return y
```

`/bar`

```
 def get(...):
   return True
```

- **b service**

gRPC service with `rpc FooBar`

```
rpc FooBar

def FooBar(...):
   return requests.get("/bar")
```

If client hits endpoint `/foo` in **a service**:

1. Code hits rpc FooBar in **b service**
2. FooBar rpc can't hits `/bar` endpoint in **a service** as  that service is blocked.

AFAIK, using **x=await test()** should prevent us of such blocking, what I have missed?

Comment: `await` doesn't automatically make your code non-blocking. Are those rpc calls asynchronous? If not, then that'll cause blocking.

Comment: @xyres yes rpc call is synchronous. But problem is that tornado service is blocked, not grpc service

Comment: Yeah, if rpc calls are not async, then they will block the tornado process (because you're making those calls from the tornado process).

Comment: @xyres there is no way to "bypass" it having sync rpc call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the rpc calls aren't async, it will block the Tornado process.

You can avoid blocking the main process by running the rpc calls in a separate thread.

First, make the `test()` method regular function, not a coroutine (remove the `async` keyword).

Example code:

```
async def get(...): 
    x = await IOLoop.current().run_in_executor(None, test)
    return x

# regular function, not async
def test(...):
    # make calls
    return x
```